# navigation in custom uitableviewcell

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

I have created a custom uitableviewcell in a seperate class and using it in a viewcontroller in a uitableview. Now I want to navigate user to another page on click of a button in my custom uitableviewcell. can someone please help me?

Following is my code of action on button click in uitableviewcell:

```
 -(IBAction)followUser:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"memberid %d",self.memberid);
    profileViewController *profile = [[profileViewController alloc] init];
    [((UIViewController*) sender).navigationController pushViewController:profile animated:FALSE];

}
```

But it is crashing.

Answer (score 1):

The sender parameter of your action method 'followUser:' refers to the control that called the method. This is probably a UIButton. And obviously a UIButton doesn't have a 'navigationController' property. If your code is inside a UIViewController subclass that is on the navigation stack, then that subclass has a 'navigationController' property, via which you're able to access the UINavigationController. Try this:

```
-(IBAction)followUser:(id)sender {
NSLog(@"memberid %d",self.memberid);
profileViewController *profile = [[profileViewController alloc] init];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:profile animated:FALSE];
[profile release];
}
```

@CodaFi Nothing wrong with 'profileViewController alloc', if that's the name of his UIViewController subclass.

Comment: sender is actually the view controller on which I have added the the tableview. The tableview has custom tableview cells and these cells have this button on whose action my code is being called. So your answer is not going to hold as the UIButton is not present on the UIViewcontroller instead it is present on UITableviewCell.

Answer (score 0):

[profileViewController alloc] is wrong.  You want the actual class of the object to be allocated, not it's instance variable.